# rails undefined method 'cashes_page'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good day, could you give me a hand with this problem:

I added to my store_controller

```
cashes_page :index
```

application.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

application_controller.rb

```
include ActionController::Caching
```

And i get `undefined method 'cashes_page' for StoreController:Class`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not cashes_page :index

```
caches_page :index
```

Answer (score 5):

Page caching has been removed in Rails 4, along with other things such as observers, protected model attributes and ActiveResource. The good news is that if we need any of these features, it’s easy to add them back through gems. We’ll add a list of items that it’s a good idea to use during the upgrade process.

`gem 'actionpack-page_caching'`
`gem 'actionpack-action_caching'`

Answer (score 1):

Might be a typo.
Instead of cashes_page :index, use `caches_page :index`